# Elinks browser - howto paste without mouse?

Tags: linux, browser, command-line

Is it somehow possible to paste a URL in elinks? 
I am connected per SSH and cannot use the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, I realise, but, comes up as the top result in google when searching for how to copy/paste in elinks - so as I have an answer, here it is, for the benefit of future searchers...

If connected via SSH and you are happy to use the mouse to copy/paste, but, it's not working as expected, you can just hold shift while clicking, e.g. using Putty for SSH, hold shift, left click and drag to select/copy and hold shift and right click to paste.

Source: http://elinks.or.cz/faq.html

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is a few months old, but...

If you are using putty in windows, go to
`Terminal > Features` when configuring the connection.Then you need to check `Disable xterm-style mouse reporting`. This will allow you to right-click to paste in elinks (or any other program that blocks the mouse) just like you'd expect it to.